# Apply a list of attributes to xml element dynamically

Tags: xml, scala

Say I have a list of attribute tuples:

```
val list = List(("name", "myname"), ("id", "1"))
```

How would I then dynamically generate and XML element thus:

```
<elem name='myname' id='1'/>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure your case is more complicated, but as far as the question goes: `"<elem " + list.map(tp => s"${tp._1}='${tp._2}'").mkString(" ") + " />"`

Comment: Is there not some way to use the scala.xml.Attribute object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard interface to work with XML in Scala is not very convenient. Attributes are stored in a linked list `xml.MetaData` (which is not actually a `List` or any kind of collection whatsoever). So you would have to fold your list to produce this `MetaData`. After that the easiest way to make an element with it in my opinion is to use `%` operator. The other way to construct an element is to pass this `MetaData` to `xml.Elem` constructor.

```
val list = List(("name", "myname"), ("id", "1"))
val attributeList = list.foldLeft(xml.Null: xml.MetaData) {
  case (metadata, (key, value)) => xml.Attribute(None, key, xml.Text(value), metadata) 
}
val elem = <elem/> % attributeList
```